# как сверстать блок с откосами

Tags: css3, html5

затрудняюсь с этим треугольником справа

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Вариант:

стрелка справа сделана за счет `transform: scale(0.2,1) rotate(45deg);` это дает ромб, у которого взяты 2 бордера

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 152px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 9px;
  border-right:transparent;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: -3px 0px 4px 0px rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px; 
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top:26px;
  transform: scale(0.2,1) rotate(45deg);
}

div:before {
  font-family:arial;
  color:red;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Смотреть все';
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  top:60px;
  left:-30px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```